# My bag is not full, so why can't I catch any Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have only 118 items in my bag, so it is not full, yet I'm being told it is full. When it said that the bag was full initially, I threw many items away. I'm now left with 118 items, but every time I try to catch a Pokémon, it says my bag is full.

I've tried logging out and back in and removing Pokémon Go from my Google account, but nothing is fixing this.

Answer (score 5):

Your item bag is different from your Pokémon bag. Throwing items out will *not* free up your Pokémon bag.

[image: pokemon bag]

[image: item bag]

To be able to catch more Pokémon, you'll need to release some Pokémon or expand your Pokémon storage until you are no longer at capacity.